# Get more info out of a Python3 OSError

Tags: python, exception, hid

I am using Python3 on Ubuntu with the HID module [python3-hid](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/python3-hid).

If I use it to open a device, I simply get back:

```
OSError: open failed
```

Which prompted me to handle the exception, and see if I can get more information out of it:

```
    try:
        h.open(vend, prod)
    except OSError as error :
        print(error)
        print(error.strerror)
        print(error.filename)
        sys.exit(1)
```

To my surprise, no further information was available, as both strerror and filename were None.

```
open failed
None
None
```

**NOTE**: My open() succeeds when I run as root, so I **know** this is a permission thing. But why can't this OSError tell me that it is permission related?

How do I get all the details (specific reason of failure, and filename involved) out of an OSError?

**UPDATE**: The traceback leads to hid.pyx file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/./tst.py", line 30, in <module>
    h.open(vend, prod)
  File "hid.pyx", line 66, in hid.device.open
```

I am not sure why my system can't find the hid.pyx file.

```
$ dpkg -S hid.pyx
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *hid.pyx*
```

Checking the upstream package from Ubuntu... it turns out that python3-hid is part of the software for a crypto coin wallet? Strange. I think I will skip using this module, and maybe write directly in C, using libhidapi-hidraw which this python module also uses.

Comment: Did you check the source code of the package? This doesn't look like standard `OSError` message from Python Standard Library. Most likely the code raise `OSError` with only limited amount of information.

Comment: Was there a traceback? In your exception handler you could add `import traceback;traceback.print_exc()`. That could show you more details of where the error happened in HID which could help track down the problem. A permissions error from vanilla python would look like `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'thefile'`. It sounds like HID could use a feature update for better error messages.

Comment: `For correct functionality under Linux, you need to create a rule file similar to this one in your udev rules directory.` [github: cython-hidapi](https://github.com/trezor/cython-hidapi#udev-rules)

Comment: @diggusbickus Yeah, I saw that. My issue is with getting the error info out of Python, not so much as actually solving the error.

Comment: then you saw the hid.pyx file, and the throwing of `raise IOError('open failed')`. and if you can't find the file it's probably because it's compiled into `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/hidraw.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`